# How to get mobile site in Firefox to be displayed as in Chrome for Android if spoofing doesn't help?

Tags: browser, chrome-for-android, firefox-for-android

On my Android device, while using Internet, Dolphin, and Firefox (left), I see the same version of http://m.chase.com that my desktop browser (right) sees:

[image: Chase Mobile on Firefox] [image: Chase Mobile on Other browser]

---

On Chrome for Android (left), it's different, being similar to what opens iOS browser (right):

[image: Chase Mobile on Chrome for Android] [image: Chase Mobile on iOS]

I want to understand why/how, and then see if I can get Mobile Firefox to load the blue version. I don't think it's the user agent string - I've tried spoofing it already.

Comment: Seems to be mobile site on iOS. I get the mobile site on the default android browser. Could just be how the site is programmed.

Comment: A number of sites check to see if certain features are supported by the browser, which can't really be spoofed (doing so would be adding the functionality!).  For a bank site I would assume said features are required for that version of the site to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that both iOS browser (safari) and Chrome (desktop or for Android) are based on [WebKit engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit). That's why they are so similar in what they render.

Firefox browser uses a much different engine: [Gecko](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gecko_(layout_engine)).

As an answer for what you want to do, I think that given the CSS and javascript the mobile site loads is different depending on the rendering engine, currently it is not possible to an end user to achieve that. A better design must be done by web developers who made the website, in order to avoid this kind of awkward situations.

If what you need is to open that mobile site with a browser different to Chrome for Android, but that it be rendered the same way as Chrome for Android does, I recommend you to use [Opera Mobile](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.opera.browser) or [Opera Mini](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.opera.mini.android) (based on [Presto](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presto_(layout_engine)) engine), here is a screenshot of how it looks there:

[image: Chase mobile on Opera]

Comment: Agh, that sucks. There really shouldn't be any reason their webkit site wouldn't render the same in Firefox, but I guess I'm just gonna have to live with it.

Comment: Yeah, we (web developers) have to struggle with it on a daily basis: to make the websites to render in a given way, regardless of browser being used. In some scenarios, like this, the goal is not reached. That depends on the quality of web developers too, and in the pressure from higher levels (deadlines).